# My formatted CSS button is not aligning properly

Tags: html, css

I've formatted a button to be center aligned and in the middle of a webpage, but I'm not seeing the changes. I've posted code below. Thanks in advance!

```css
.btn-2 {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    position: fixed;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #B22234;
    border-radius: 100px;
    position: absolute; 
  width: 400px;
    top: 210%;
    color: #fff;
```

Comment: Hi @Abammer, can you please post the HTML code as well?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please provide [mre] in order to help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simple just remove position fixed and add `transform:translateX(-50%);left:50%;` after position absolute

```
.btn-2 {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px 30px;
    font-weight: 200px;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #B22234;
    border-radius: 100px;
    width: 400px;
    position:absolute;
    transform:translateX(-50%);
    left:50%;
    top: 210%;
    color: #fff;
}

<button class="btn-2">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are using `position: absolute;` - lets add `left: 50%; transform: translateX(-50%);` to center the element.

```css
.btn-2 {
  display: flex;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  font-weight: 200px;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #B22234;
  border-radius: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 400px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  /*top: 210%;*/ /* will hide it for this example, optional*/
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn-2">Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to center items you can use two easy approaches:

**1. Old fashion transform trick**

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

`left` and `top` will translate the item within the parent, and `transform` will translate it relative to its top left corner.

`position: fixed;` also work as long as you know the differences between `absolute` and `fixed`.

**2. Flex approach**

You need to work with the parent. You must set the following properties to the parent:

```
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
```

The child should also have `display: flex;` for easy handling, but it's not mandatory. `position: absolute;` is not necessary with this approach.

Comment: Thanks Cristian I will keep this approach in mind going forward as well.